# Filter on boolean field in Django

Tags: python, django

On my view I only want to show the archived posts. 
As you can see below I have a model on a BooleanField. 
How do I have to define it in my view?
Thanks

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

That is how I did it

```
def post_list_archived(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(archived=True).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: Er, like that? What is wrong with this code?

Comment: sorry, I used the wrong functions in the URLs

Comment: This should work properly.
My only comment is that you better use the option `auto_now_add` on the `created_date` field rather than set the default value to `timezone.now()`.
So it could be like `created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Comment: BTW is the problem that you are seeing ALL the posts or that you are seeing NO posts?
And what does the `post_list.html` template look like?